# Knockout failing to post a form, can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, typescript

I am developing a page with ASP.NET MVC and API, using Knockout, Typescript, and the code is as: [JSFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/YcTtD/)

The server code:

```
// POST: api/Empresas
    [ResponseType(typeof(Business))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostBusiness(Business business)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Businesses.Add(business);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = business.Id }, business);
    }
```

Business Obj:

```
public class Business
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "CNPJ", Description = "Cadastro Nacional de Pessoa Juridica")]
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Nome", Description = "Razão Social")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Limite Mensal", Description = "Limite mensal de uso")]
    public int MonthlyLimit { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Mensal Atual", Description = "Uso Mensal Atual")]
    public int MonthlyCurrent { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Inicio Assinatura", Description = "Data inicial da assinatura")]
    public DateTime SubscriptionStart { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Meses Contratados", Description = "Numero de meses contratados")]
    public int MonthContractCount { get; set; }
}
```

The example is not gonna work since there is not an end point to test against.
My first question is why won't the data-bind work for this?
Second and most important, I keep getting the following error message:

---

### Message from webpage

[object Object]
parsererror

### SyntaxError: Invalid character - failed to create business

### OK

I have no idea why this is happening, and I have done multiple changes to the code with success. Any ideas?

Values I was using:
CNPJ = 123.321.321-25
Name = Test Business
monthlyLimit = 20000
SubscriptionStart = 01/01/2014
monthContractCount = 24

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
createBusiness = (formElement) => {}
```

I changed the signature on the method to look like the above, with attempt to solve the scope problem with "this" key word. Still not working though.

NEW EDIT:

```
createBusiness = (formElement) => {
        $(formElement).validate();
        if ($(formElement).valid()) {
            var formserialized = $(formElement).serialize();
            $.post('/Api/Empresas/', formserialized, null, "json")
                .done((result) => {
                    this.Business.Id = result.Id;
                    this.Business.Name(result.Name);
                    this.Business.CNPJ(result.CNPJ);
                    this.Business.MonthlyLimit(result.MonthlyLimit);
                    this.Business.SubscriptionStart(result.SubscriptionStart);
                    this.Business.MonthContractCount(result.MonthContractCount);
                    this.Business.MonthlyCurrent(result.MonthlyCurrent);
                })
                .fail((x, y, z) => {
                    alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z + ' - failed to create business');
                });
        };
    }
```

This is the last change, and it worked now, but as you can see I had to change the this.BaseUri to '/Api/Empresas/' this change was necessary due to scope of "this", so this is a fix but not really. Any ideas there?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var formserialized = $(formElement).serialize();
```

to

```
var formserialized = JSON.stringify($(formElement).serialize());
```

Comment: could you show us the JSON in your request? this can be retrieved using Chrome's dev tool (Network tab)

Comment: This is the content of the request body after the suggestion:

"cnpj=123.321.123-58&name=Test+Business&monthlyLimit=20000&SubscriptionStart=01%2F01%2F2014&monthContractCount=24"

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with the scope, with "this", I did change the code as the edit above.

Comment: Ok, the request body is not a valid JSON, change the above line to  var formserialized = JSON.stringify($(formElement).serializeArray());

[jquery serializearray api](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: This is the resulting json, which does not deserialize correctly to the object above (Resulted in a 500).

[{"name":"cnpj","value":"123.321.123-35"},{"name":"name","value":"Test Empresa"},{"name":"monthlyLimit","value":"20000"},{"name":"SubscriptionStart","value":"01/01/2014"},{"name":"monthContractCount","value":"24"}]

Comment: why don't you use knockout's json serialiser to serialise your ko vm object and pass it back to the server instead? var formserialized = ko.toJSON(this);

Comment: Very good sugestion @Duy but because of the scope the resulting JSON is not good (does not deserilize).
{"BaseUri":"/Api/Empresas/","Business":{"Id":null,"Name":"Test Business 2","CNPJ":"321.456.987-45","MonthlyLimit":"20000","SubscriptionStart":"01/01/2014","MonthContractCount":"24","Users":[]}}

Notice the scope is the BusinessView instead of the Business, as it was supposed to.